# How to center align a checkbox in handsontable?

Tags: handsontable

I am using handsontable and my code is written in typescript/aurelia. I cannot center align the checkbox column. I followed [this](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/demo-alignment.html) link and set the className on my checkbox column to "htCenter htMiddle". On text columns this thing works but not on the checkbox column. Whereas when I use my dev tools and set the class on the `<td>` to "htCenter htMiddle", it works. Is there any other way to set the alignment for this checkbox column?

Here is the code for adding the className:

`this.options.columns = [
                    { data: "modalValue", renderer: linkButtonRenderer, readOnly: true },
                    { data: "uri", readOnly: true },
                    { data: "isPublic", className: "htCenter htMiddle", type: "checkbox" }
                ];`

Comment: How are you setting the class names? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Have edited and put the code in the question.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? I'm not sure it works on columns, it might be a `cells` only option.

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem. It seems like check boxes are somehow special: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made my own fix for this issue for Handsontable 0.19.0

```
[handsontable.full.js: line 17197]
function checkboxRenderer(instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties)
```

adding this to allow using custom renderers (don't know why they missed this)

```
getRenderer('base').apply(this, arguments);
```

If you just want to hardcode the align, put this as a first line in that function:

```
TD.style.textAlign = "center";
```

Comment: I had adopted the second method which you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set

```
{ data: 'Is_anything', type: 'checkbox', className: "htCenter htMiddle" },
```

like this. You will get checkbox in center.

Answer (score 2):

The inability to set checkbox (and numeric) alignment was a bug in previous versions of Handsontable.  This has been fixed as of [Handsontable version **0.25.1**](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/releases/tag/0.25.1) --- see https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2925 and https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3532.

The OP's code should now work.